# jquery javascript add/remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form, where I dynamically want to add additional inputfields. So when I click the "Add"-button, there should appear a new inputfield but now with both an add and remove button. When I now click the "Add" button next to the new inputfield, there shoud appear another new inputfield et. etc. The same goes fro the remove button. So far, so good... my issue is though, that I cant create a new inputfield after clicking "Add"...

So, my code looks like this:

```
<div id="fields">
   <button class="add">Add</button> 
   <div class="newField">
     <div class="check">
        <input type="radio" id="field_1" name="correct" required></input>
     </div>
     <input type="text" id="input_1" required></input>                  
   </div>           
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
#fields {
  width:350px
} 

.check{
  float:left
}

.add, .remove {
  float:right
}
```

and most important, the javascript:

```
var InputsWrapper   = $("#fields");
var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
var FieldCount=1; 

$('.add').click(function(e){
FieldCount++; 
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="newField"><button class="remove">Remove</button><button class="add">Add</button><div class="check"><input type="radio" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" name="correct"></div><input type="text" id="input_'+ FieldCount +'" /></div></div>');
x++;
return false;
});

$(document).on("click",".remove", function(e){ 
   if( x > 1 ) {
     $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
     x--; 
   }
  return false;
});
```

Here is a **DEMO** fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwprf03o/

Can someone help me out?

Comment: just to point out `InputsWrapper` is already a jQuery object, so there is no reason to wrap it in jQuery selector again. remove the `$()` from the call to append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace line

`$('.add').click(function(e){`

with

`$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e){`

The reason for this is that the `click()` function binds your `function(e){}` to `.add` elements that exist **at the time the `click()` function is called**.

The `on()` method works differently. On the click event it will also search for any `.add` items that exist **at the time the click event is raised**.

http://jsfiddle.net/1qq40qex/

Comment: This is super! What if I just want to show the "remove" button next to the inputfield and only the last field has the "add" button?

Comment: My bedtime now. Will answer tomorrow if nobody else has.

Comment: awesome! I really appreciate it :-)

Comment: Fix is here. I've also removed the unnecessary $() as pointed out by r3wt. Other improvements could be made. http://jsfiddle.net/1qq40qex/2/

Comment: Wow thats great! Super nice! Thanks alot! :-)